# How do I switch to landscape orientation

Tags: flutter, agora.io

I am using the Agora Flutter Quickstart project. By default the orientation is portrait but I want to switch to landscape. Therefor I have to implement these lines:

```
VideoEncoderConfiguration videoEncoderConfiguration = new 
VideoEncoderConfiguration();
videoEncoderConfiguration.orientationMode = 
    VideoOutputOrientationMode.FixedLandscape;
AgoraRtcEngine.setVideoEncoderConfiguration(videoEncoderConfiguration);
```

I don't know where to place these lines. I've tried a lot but the the orientation is still portrait

Answer (score 0):

Import hte following package `package:flutter/services.dart`
Then add the code below into your build Method of the main App widget

```
SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
    DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
]);
```

This will allow only landscape mode for your app.

Comment: It's still the same. The page is in landscape mode but the video is in portrait mode